# How can I wait for a period of time after a button is clicked?

Tags: android, wait, runnable

So I have an activity which runs a simple snakes and ladders game, and I want to allow the player to click a button and move, which would subsequently be followed by the computer moving. My problem is, that once the player moves, the computer immediately makes its move.

Instead I want the activity to wait before the computer makes its move. I've looked around a lot and found that waiting involves using a thread, but I have failed to implement it without my app crashing

My attempt at declaring a thread:

```
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()  {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    };

    Thread thread= new Thread(runnable);
```

My onClick() method for the button:

```
Button rollButton = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.rollButton));
    rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //executes only if current player is a human
            if(GAME_BOARD.getCurrentPlayer().isHuman()) {

                GAME_BOARD.rollDie(); // rolls the die
                showDie(GAME_BOARD); // displays die on screen      
                GAME_BOARD.move();  // moves the player and sets next player as current player
                playerTurn.setText(GAME_BOARD.getCurrentPlayer().getName() +"'s turn");// sets TextView to display who's player's turn it is
                thread.start();  

                if(!GAME_BOARD.getCurrentPlayer().isHuman()) {

                    GAME_BOARD.rollDie();
                    showDie(GAME_BOARD);
                    GAME_BOARD.move();
                    playerTurn.setText(GAME_BOARD.getCurrentPlayer().getName() +"'s turn");                 
                }   
            }

        }
    });
```

So again, my question is, how do I make it so that before the second if statement executes, the activity waits, say 4 seconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you have the code pause for a couple of seconds in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111905/how-do-you-have-the-code-pause-for-a-couple-of-seconds-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use an `Handler.postDeleayed`. You have to provide a Runnable to execut and the delay period in milliseconds. The `Runnable` will be executed on the UI Thread

Answer (score 3):

You can use Handle to post your task defined in runnable after some delay

use this
Inside Activity define

```
Handler hand = new Handler();
```

and define your task in runnable like this

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() { 
    @Override 

    public void run() { 

      **your Task here.......**
    } 

};
```

In on click event

```
btnStartShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            hand.postDelayed(run,3000); // For delay three seconds
        }
    });
```

also remove all pending messages by  calling following sentence at appropriate place

```
hand.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CountDownTimer:

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                *function containing the second statement*
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisLeft) {
                // not ticking
            }
        };
```

and in the onClick method in the click listener use:

```
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // whatever you would like to implement when or after clicking rollButton
            }
        };
        rollButton.postDelayed(runnable, 5000); //Delay for 5 seconds to show the result
}
```