# How to pause an android app

Tags: android

I want to make an app that displays some info on the screen, waits a while and then continue to display something else. Is there a simple command to pause an android app? I'm using android 4.2.2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111905/how-do-you-have-the-code-pause-for-a-couple-of-seconds-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Handler class:

Make an instance:

```
    Handler h=new Handler();
```

Use your instance to run the postDelayed() method:

```
   final boolean    postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)
```

Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses.

The postDelayed() method has to be feeded with a Runnable containing the code which you want to occur after the delayMillis milliseconds.

The runnable class can be made as following:

```
    class Runner extends Runnable{ 
         public void run() { 
             //Your codes
         }
    }
```

As a simple example:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runner(), 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks! The view I used also contained the postDelayed() method, so I used that one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by removing the timer ..

Sample code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
my_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
// SLEEP 2 SECONDS HERE ...
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() { 
          my_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.defaultcard); 
     } 
}, 2000); 
}
```

Am not an android developer..I recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android).I got the answer from there ..Hope it helps ..

Answer (score 1):

You could use Thread.sleep()

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There might be better ways but this is the one I learnt.