# How to make an activity flash at the beginning of the app?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app.In this,at the beginning of the app an activity will be displayed for 2 seconds and after that the app with start with the main activity.
This is how i tried to achieve this:

The activity_main.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,open.class);
    startActivity(i);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#A6250F")));
    bar.setSubtitle(R.string.title_sub);
}
```

}

The open.java file

```
public class open extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.open);
        android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#A6250F")));
}
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finish();
}
```

}

The open.java file should be shown for 2 seconds at the beginning of the app and then the execution will continue from the activity_main.java

But what happens is a blank screen is displayed for a second and then the mainactivity is shown.Need help

Comment: basically you have blocked Ui thread with `Thread.sleep(2000);` ... you should find better solution ...  hint: similar code is used inside "splash screen"

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4114569/2835243). That's pretty much what you want to do.

Comment: Google splash screen for android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should re-design your flow so that :

open is the Activity that is created first, and 2 seconds after loads the MainActivity.

```
public class open extends Activity {
  private Activity  mActivity;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.open);
    android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#A6250F")));
    mActivity = this;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent(mActiviy, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
      }
    }
    handler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
  }
}
```

Last thing is make sure you swap the Activities in your Manifest, making your application start with the `open` Activity