# Android: how to check if the connection with the store is ready

Tags: java, android

I am developing a software that has some in app purchase.
I've created a store `activity` that works, the sole purpose of the store is to buy 1 element that allow you to remove ads.
The problem arise when I'm implementing the process of checking if the user has already bought the item in the `MainActivity`.
This is how I handle the connection:

```
    IInAppBillingService mService;
    ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.calculator_toobar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        //Opening a connection with the store
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        //Some more code...

        CheckPurchase();
    }
```

More specifically my problem arise whenever I tried to call `CheckPurchase`, a method I created to check if the user has indeed bought the item.
On the store activity this method work perfectly, therefore I'm convinced that this is not an issue with the method (on the store the `CheckPurchase` method is called when a button is pressed).

I think that this issue is caused by a bad timing.
The reason I believe so is because: when I create a button, in the `MainActivity`, that has the sole purpose of calling the method (and I remove `CheckPurchase` from the `onCreate` method), the method `CheckPurchase` works, and I receive a proper response.
I think that the problem is related to the time it takes to set up a connection, and that the `onCreathe` method is too fast.

My question than becomes the following:

Is there a way to wait until the connection is fully set up?

Is there some sort of command available to check if the connection is ready and set up?

Or should I simply use [something like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111905/how-do-you-have-the-code-pause-for-a-couple-of-seconds-in-android)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a friend of mine pointed out, apparently the best way to do something after the connection is established, is to use the `onServiceConnected` method.

The previous code becomes:

```
    IInAppBillingService mService;
    ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }

        //In this class everything is done after the connection is established.
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
            //I added this line of code to make sure that the check was made only after the connection was established
            CheckPurchase();
        }
    };
```