# Android show backwards array list elements

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a clickable TextView where when you press it, it retrieves elements from an Array list and shows them randomly on the same TextView.. Every time you press the TextView, it shows another element.

Now, I want to save those elements with the order that are shown and after that, with the press of a previous button, show every time the previous element of the one that is been desplayed, until the first one..

I try it by myself, but it keeps only one element and not all those that been shown and doesn't display them backwards.

```
ArrayList<String> random = new ArrayList<String>();

Text_View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (myString==null||myString.size()==0){
                        myString = new ArrayList<String>();
                        Collections.addAll(myString,res.getStringArray(R.array.Text_array));
                        Collections.shuffle(myString);
                    }
                    String q = myString.remove(0);
                    Text_View.setText(q);


                    for (int i=0;i<myString.size();i++) {
                        random.add(q);
                    }
                }

            });

            prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    for (int counter = myString.size() - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
                        Text_View.setText(random.get(counter));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Thank you..

**UPDATE**
I am posting the code with the correction that you have pointed, but still doesn't work, but even worse, it crashes!
     public class MyActivity extends Activity {

```
public int counter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.family_excuses);

       Text_View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

                   int counter = myString.size() - 1;

                    if (myString==null||myString.size()==0){
                        myString = new ArrayList<String>();
                        Collections.addAll(myString,res.getStringArray(R.array.Text_array));
                        Collections.shuffle(myString);
                    }
                    String q = myString.remove(0);
                    Text_View.setText(q);

                    for (int i=0;i<myString.size();i++) {
                        random.add(q);
                    }
                }
            });

            prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Text_View.setText(random.get(counter));
                    counter--;

                }
            });
```

**UPDATE 2**
I make the new changes. The button works without crashing even if I press it more than one times, but still, I get every time only the first shown element. The new code is:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

public int counter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.family_excuses);

       Text_View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

                    Resources res = getResources();

                    if (myString==null||myString.size()==0){
                        myString = new ArrayList<String>();
                        Collections.addAll(myString,res.getStringArray(R.array.Text_array));
                        Collections.shuffle(myString);
                    }
                    String q = myString.remove(0);
                    Text_View.setText(q);

                    for (int i=0;i<myString.size();i++) {
                        random.add(q);
                    }
                }
            });

            prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                   int counter = myString.size() - 2;

                    if (counter>=0){

                    Text_View.setText(random.get(counter));
                    counter--;

                }
```

sorry, I don't know how to use the console..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change second update to this

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

public int counter;
private static final String TAG = "whatever"; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.family_excuses);

       Text_View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

                    Resources res = getResources();

                    if (myString==null||myString.size()==0){
                        myString = new ArrayList<String>();
                        Collections.addAll(myString,res.getStringArray(R.array.Text_array));
                        Collections.shuffle(myString);
                        counter = myString.size() - 2;

                    }
                    String q = myString.remove(0);
                    Text_View.setText(q);

                    for (int i=0;i<myString.size();i++) {
                        random.add(q);
                    }
                }
            });

            prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    if (counter>=0){
                    Log.i(TAG,Integer.toString(counter));
                    Text_View.setText(random.get(counter));
                    counter--;

                }
```

connect your phone to your computer,open the android monitor, run the app and search(it has a search bar)for your tag(here, it is called whatever). it will filter the results, so post them here.also, tell me how many items there are in the Text_array,how many times you clicked on text_View and how many on prev. for example, what happens when you press textview 3(or more) times first?

I am going to bed, see you in the morning

EDIT 1:this should work, I created a project to test it and it works for me

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public int counter;
    private static final String TAG = "whatever";
    ArrayList <String> myString=null;
    private TextView Text_View;
    private Button prev;
    public ArrayList<String> random=new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.family_excuses);
        Text_View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text_View);
        prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);//request location

        Text_View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Resources res = getResources();

                if (myString==null||myString.size()==0){
                    myString = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Collections.addAll(myString,res.getStringArray(R.array.Text_array));
                    Collections.shuffle(myString);

                }
                String q = myString.remove(0);
                Text_View.setText(q);

                    random.add(q);
                counter=random.size()-2;

            }
        });

        prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (counter >= 0) {

                    Text_View.setText(random.get(counter));
                    counter--;

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the only issue should be that it doesnt work if you press textview>prev>textview, but we will fix that too, i just want to make sure it works for you too

EDIT 2: this should be the final version, this works for textview>prev>textview.
I am not sure the line should be mark=counter+2;, feel free to change the number, because I am still confused about what you are trying to do

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public int counter;
    private static final String TAG = "whatever";
    ArrayList <String> myString=null;
    private TextView Text_View;
    private Button prev;
    private int mark=-1;
    public ArrayList<String> random=new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.family_excuses);
        Text_View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text_View);
        prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);//request location

        Text_View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Resources res = getResources();

                if (myString==null||myString.size()==0){
                    myString = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Collections.addAll(myString,res.getStringArray(R.array.Text_array));
                    Collections.shuffle(myString);

                }
                String q = myString.remove(0);
                Text_View.setText(q);
                Log.i(TAG,Integer.toString(mark));
                if (mark==-1){

                    random.add(q);

                }else {
                    random.add(mark,q);
                }
                counter=random.size()-2;

            }
        });

        prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (counter >= 0) {

                    Text_View.setText(random.get(counter));
                    counter--;
                    mark=counter+2;

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.. alright, I press Run while I run the app on my mobile..
It didn't show anything when I pressed the Text_view, only with the previous button.. I pressed 5 times Text_view, 2 previous, 3 Text_view, 4 previous, 6 Text_views and 1 previous..
the result was:
I/whatever: 20
I/whatever: 19
I/whatever: 18
I/whatever: 17
I/whatever: 16
I/whatever: 15
I/whatever: 14
If there is anything else I have to do to see results, please tell me.. Thank you, goodnight!!

Comment: You are welcome.I was looking at the comment where you gave an example, i try to understand it. Lets say you have values 1-5, randomized as 2,4,3,5,1. After pressing textview 4 times, you should have 2,4,3,5. If you press textview one more time, you will get 2,4,3,5,1. but if you instead press prev 2 times and then textview, you will get 2,4,1,3,5. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right, it was what I want! Thanks again!!

Comment: added new version, see if it does what you want

Comment: I tested it and the first version is more correct than the second.. Thank you very much for the try!!!

Comment: I have problem!! I just realise that when I press the previous button for the very first time, without press not even once the Text_view, the app crashes.. ->I open the app -> press the previous button ->crashes!!! Could you figure out what might be the problem?? Thank you!!

Comment: That's easy, create a global boolean variable (e.g clicked) and initialize it as false. In text view, set it as true. In prev, put all lines inside an if (clicked) block. Basically what happens is you use counter and random without giving them values first

Comment: alright... I put on the top Boolean clicked=false; then, inside the textview, I put on the final row clicked=true; and the button (inside) I made it : if(clicked=true){ if (counter >= 0) { Text_view.setText(random.get(counter));
counter--;}} but still error :(

Comment: pfff I fix it.. for some reason it didn't want the boolean, so I try an integer 0 in the beginning and inside the textview 1.. On previous button, I put the if as you said and it works!!!! Thanks a looooot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change Text_View.setText(q);
to Text_View.append(q);
EDIT: change it to this:

```
prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    Text_View.setText(random.get(counter));
                counter--;
            }
        });
```

give a value to counter in Text_View.setOnClickListener

```
counter = myString.size() - 1;
```

and initialize it with your global variables, for example

```
public class yourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int counter;
```

EDIT 2 add delay to your original answer

```
    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

                    for (int counter = myString.size() - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
                        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                doStuff(random.get(i));
            }
        }, 5000);

                    }
                }
            });

    private void doStuff(String i) {
    Text_View.setText(i);
    }
```

and add the handlers to your imported libraries

Comment: The first part (show random the elements after click), works perfect.. the problem is with the save in a arraylist and show the backwards..  thank you

Comment: have you tried removing the for loop? perhaps it shows everything too fast for you to see, you want to change the text only when you click, if I understand you correctly

Comment: I just remove the first for loop and it crashed.. :(

Comment: I meant for (int counter = myString.size() - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
                        Text_View.setText(random.get(counter));
                    }

Comment: I made it "Text_View.setText(random.get(myString.size()-1));" but it only shows the first element and not the previous of the last one..

Comment: I change it an put int counter = myString.size() - 1; into Text_View.setOnClickListener, but inside the prev.setOnClickListener it doesn't recognize the "counter"..

Comment: my bad, add int counter; in your global variables (right after public class yourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   ) and remove the int from Text_View (I will edit my answer)

Comment: Even without press the button, it just crashes the app...
I am going to post the code, maybe I have made a mistake..

Comment: where do you create myString? if it happens in the ClickListener, you are assigning the counter a value that doesnt exist, move counter = myString.size() - 1; at the end of the first if

Comment: I try to put right after first if (and inside the end of the first if), but when I press the button, it shows only the first element and not the previous.. Also, when I press it for second time, it crashed..
Sorry for the insist and thanks for the help, but it drives me crazy..

Comment: wait, if I understand you correctly, you want all those elements to appear after only 1 click (click->element->wait->element->etc)?I am sorry, I thought you meant each new element appearing after each click(click->element->click->element).In this case,your first answer was, correct, just add delay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111905/how-do-you-have-the-code-pause-for-a-couple-of-seconds-in-android  I will edit my answer with more detailed code

Comment: I don't want to have any delay. let me clear it out. The user, press the TextView and appears randomly elements from an array list. When the user presses the previous button, it has to show the previous element that has been shown. every time he presses previous button, no matter how many times, it has to show all the elements, one by one, backward.
If the user starts to press again the TextView and new random elements from the array list appears, those, must be shown backward when he press previous button. So, I need somewhere to save every random element is shown and show them backwards.

Comment: you need a delay, because otherwise the different values will appear too fast, and you will only see the last. unless you want all of them to appear on text simultaneously,in which case change Text_View.setText(random.get(counter)); to Text_View.append(random.get(counter)); in your original code

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I don't get it.. I want to appear the previous element with the prev button..not all the elements.. only when the button is pressed.. ex.If has been appeared the elements with the row: 9,6,7,2,4,1,3,5,8 when the user press prev, shows 5, prev ->3, prev->1, prev->4 etc... 
If the user is on 4 and wants to press again the TextView to continue, it continuous from 4 but keeps the previous ex. the new would be: 9,6,7,2,4,8,6,3,1 and every time the user press previous button, with every click, will show 1,3,6,8,4,2,7,6,9.

Comment: okay, ignore the latest 2 comments. when creating counter, make it myString.size() - 2; to show previous to last. also, place the print and counter -- in prev in an if statement that checks if counter>=0. last, add some logs to print the counter value to console just before printing random,and give us the results

Comment: I am going to make an update2 on top to be sure, because still doesn't work correctly