# Run on Main Thread after time

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a function that needs to be called in the main thread because is related to bluetooth. Things is that I need to wait like 600-800 ms before executing it.
Is there any way to execute code in the main thread after some time (without waiting in that thread because it would freeze the app)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111905/how-do-you-have-the-code-pause-for-a-couple-of-seconds-in-android) should solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: @gbruscatto Yeah that solves my problem, I don't know if you should answer the question or if I should close the question.

Comment: I just added an answer. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class to do that: "There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own". The selected answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111905/how-do-you-have-the-code-pause-for-a-couple-of-seconds-in-android) should solve your problem. Good luck.